# Dropping role in PostgresSQL

Tags: postgresql

I am having the same issue dropping a role. Did so much research on google but no help.

SQL Error [2BP01]: ERROR: role "readonly" cannot be dropped because some objects depend on it Detail: privileges for default privileges on new relations belonging to role rohit in schema public

Here is what I did to drop role readonly.

```
REVOKE USAGE ON SCHEMA public FROM readonly;
REVOKE ALL ON SCHEMA public FROM readonly;


REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public FROM readonly;
REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL SEQUENCES IN SCHEMA public FROM readonly;
REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL FUNCTIONS IN SCHEMA public FROM readonly;

  
REVOKE CONNECT ON DATABASE kozuchi_db FROM readonly;
REVOKE CONNECT ON DATABASE parc_prod FROM readonly;
REVOKE CONNECT ON DATABASE postgres FROM readonly;


DROP USER readonly;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to your error message, there are some default privileges set for the role. Remove them with

```
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES FOR ROLE rohit IN SCHEMA public
   REVOKE ALL ON TABLES FROM readonly;
```

Comment: is there a quick way to see what all objects are dependent on the role? I still see error:  Error [2BP01]: ERROR: role "readonly" cannot be dropped because some objects depend on it   Detail: 1 object in database is_db   I ran command ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES FOR ROLE rohit  IN SCHEMA public
   REVOKE ALL ON TABLES FROM readonly;
followed by other commands. But still error.

Comment: No, there is no quick way. You have to remove the obstacles one by one, taking the cues from the error messages.

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```sql
DROP OWNED BY readonly;
DROP ROLE readonly;
```

Comment: I get error . SQL Error [42501]: ERROR: permission denied to drop objects. DO i need to be a superuser to do this?

Comment: Also, I do not want to drop all objects owned by readonly? I would like to drop the role readyonly.

Answer (score 0):

There should be some objects created in your Postgres cluster with the `readonly` user.

Check in the database objects and change owner of those objects, then try deleting the user.

Comment: Thanks! That is obvious. But how do I check what object has dependency to readyonly role?

Comment: Check `pg_class` / `pg_tables` to find out the objects with owner as `readonly` user. Then, change the owner of these objects.